# How to enable remote access of mysql in centos?

Tags: mysql, centos

My apache is running on `8113` port instead of `80`.

I want to access my mysql Database remotely. I have tried following steps.

```
Bind-address XXX.XX.XX.XXX in /etc/my.cnf
Create Database 
and run the command 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';
```

But not able to connect. I am using heidi sql to connect.

Comment: You need to connect to MySQL not Apache, MySQL listens in on port `3306` by default.

Comment: I am connected using port 3306. But unable to connect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

so do the following edit my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
user = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port = 3306
basedir = /usr
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir = /tmp
language = /usr/share/mysql/English
bind-address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
# skip-networking
```

after edit hit `service mysqld restart`

login into mysql and hit this query:

`GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`

thats it make sure your iptables allow connection from 3306 if not put the following:

`iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: The last command does not work. It says 'iptables v1.4.7: Can't use -i with OUTPUT'

Comment: Remove the -i parameter entirely as it's not needed on the OUTPUT rule

Answer (score 15):

Bind-address XXX.XX.XX.XXX in /etc/my.cnf

comment line:

## skip-networking

or

## skip-external-locking

after edit hit `service mysqld restart`

login into mysql and hit this query:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

add firewall rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Allow IP to mysql server linux machine. you can do following command--

```
 nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf  and add Desired IP.

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>

    Require ip 192.168.9.1(Desired IP)

</RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     #Allow from All

     Allow from 192.168.9.1(Desired IP)

</IfModule>
```

And after Update, please restart using following command--

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```